# Gorm create and return value many2many

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to create a data and then return the value, but the value is related to another table.

**User response struct**

```
type UserRespone struct {
    ID        int           `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email     string        `json:"email"`
    FirstName string        `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string        `json:"last_name"`
    Address   string        `json:"address"`
    Roles     []roles.Roles `json:"roles" gorm:"many2many:users_roles;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserID;references:ID;joinReferences:RolesID"`
}
```

**Roles struct**

```
type Roles struct {
    ID   int `json:"id" gorm:"<-:false;primaryKey"`
    Name string
}
```

And this is a function to create a data, and I want to return the value [ ]roles.Roles

```
func (r *UserRepositoryImpl) AuthSignUp(ctx context.Context, req user.AuthSignUp) (user.UserRespone, error) {
    createdUser := req.ToUser()
    
    hashPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(createdUser.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)

    createdUser.Password = string(hashPassword[:])

    result := r.Db.
        WithContext(ctx).
        Create(&createdUser)

    for _, rolesID := range req.RolesID {
        userRole := new(user.UsersRoles)

        userRole.UserID = createdUser.ID
        userRole.RolesID = rolesID
        result = r.Db.WithContext(ctx).Create(&userRole)
    }

    return createdUser.ToResponse(), result.Error
}
```

I want to return the value like this:

```
user.UserResponse{
        ID:        4,
        Email:     "putri4@gmail.com",
        FirstName: "putri",
        LastName:  "cantik",
        Address:   "bonang",
        Roles: []roles.Roles{
            {
                ID: 1,
                Name: "Admin",
            },
            {
                ID: 2,
                Name: "Consumer",
            },
        },
    }
```

But when I create a data set, I only get values like :

```
user.UserRespones{
        ID:        4,
        Email:     "putri4@gmail.com",
        FirstName: "putri",
        LastName:  "cantik",
        Address:   "bonang",
        Roles:     []roles.Roles(nil),
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you already have the user data and the role ids. I figure you just want to get the role names as well:

```
err := r.db.Find(&createdUser.Roles, req.RolesID)
// err handling
```

That said, your types and names are a bit unclear. `UserRespone` (note the typo) should probably named like `DBUser` - it isn't important whether it is used as response or something else, it represents the database entry for an user, right?

Additionally, I can only make assumptions about the type and fields of `createdUser` and `UsersRoles`, so I might have missed something.

I figure `createdUser` is of type `UserRespone` - but then I would expect that `Roles` is already complete (and you don't have to query anything at all). If not, then you should introduce a new type for that, e.g. `RequestUser` (as opposed to `DBUser`), which only contains  `Role` ids but not `Role` names. Squeezing the data from the request, the db entry and the response data into the same type is confusing (and a tad too tightly coupled for my taste).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation is a bit lacking. I've corrected my explanation.

Comment: I wonder if gorm can return values without using r.db.Find(&createdUser.Roles, req.RolesID)

Comment: @JoCerdikiawan How does `createdUser` look like, and how does `req.RolesID` look like? And do you want the roles' names be returned as well or would their ids suffice?
If not, you have to load the data with a gorm query. You won't receive the information just by inserting something.